# Getting "NameError: np is not defined", but np is defined both in main and in imported module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, nameerror

I wrote a module for my dataset classes, located in the same directory as my main file.
When i import it and try to instantiate a class i get a "np is not defined" error even though numpy is imported correctly in both the main file and the module.

I'm saying correctly because if i try both to call another numpy function from the main or to execute the module on alone no error rises.

This is the code in the main file:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from myDatasets import SFCDataset

trainDs = SFCDataset(paths["train"])
```

and this is the module:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

#Single Fragment Classification Dataset
class SFCDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, transform=None, norms=False, areas=False, **kwargs, ):
        
        super(SFCDataset, self).__init__()
        self.data = torch.load(path)
        self.fragments = []
        self.labels = []
        for item in self.data:
            self.fragments.append(item[0])
            self.labels.append(item[1])
        self.fragments=np.array(self.fragments)
        self.labels=np.array(self.labels)
        
        if norms:
            if areas:
                self.fragments = np.transpose(self.fragments[:], (0,2,1,3)).reshape(-1,1024,9)[:,:,:7]
            else:
                self.fragments = np.transpose(self.fragments[:], (0,2,1,3)).reshape(-1,1024,9)[:,:,:6]
        else:
            if areas:
                self.fragments = np.transpose(self.fragments[:], (0,2,1,3)).reshape(-1,1024,9)[:,:,[0,1,2,6]]
            else:
                self.fragments = np.transpose(self.fragments[:], (0,2,1,3)).reshape(-1,1024,9)[:,:,:3]
       
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        
        label = self.labels[index]
        pointdata = self.fragments[index]
        if self.transform:
            pointdata = self.transform(pointdata)

        return pointdata, label


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("huh")
    path = "C:\\Users\\ale23\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Università\\Tesi\\data\\dataset_1024_AB\\train_dataset_AED_norm_area.pt"
    SFCDataset(path)
```

I don't know what else to try.
I'm on VSCode, using a 3.9.13 virtual enviroment.

edit:
this is the error i'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[75], line 5
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from myDatasets import SFCDataset
----> 5 trainDs = SFCDataset(paths["train"])

File c:\Users\ale23\OneDrive\Desktop\Università\Dottorato\EquivariantNN\myDatasets.py:17, in SFCDataset.__init__(self, path, transform, norms, areas, **kwargs)
     15     self.fragments.append(item[0])
     16     self.labels.append(item[1])
---> 17 self.fragments=np.array(self.fragments)
     18 self.labels=np.array(self.labels)
     20 if norms:

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

edit2: i edited some stuff like path names and parts occuring after the error to try to lighten up the code, sorry, i should have uploaded all the code as it is run now.

Edit3: I was trying to reproduce the error in some other way and was building a dummy module. I tried to import the class in that other module and running the dummy.py and it runs. That appears to be a problem with the fact i'm working on a notebook, is that possible?

the dummy module:

```
import numpy as np

def test():
    print(np.array(1))

print(np.array(2))
print(np.sum(np.random.rand(2)))

from myDatasets import SFCDataset

trainDs=SFCDataset("C:\\Users\\ale23\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Università\\Tesi\\data\\dataset_1024_AB\\train_dataset_AED_norm_area.pt")
```

this runs by calling "python testmodule.py" in the console

Edit 4:
Today i restarted my pc and run the same code as yesterday and the notebook works. Yesterday i tried to close vscode and restart it, but it did not help.
Maybe something is wrong with the virtual environment? I don't know where to look at honestly.
Anyways the program now runs with no errors, should i close this?
Thank you all for your time and help

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of your exception? It's hard to imagine that exception coming from this code, and maybe the traceback will explain where it is really occurring.

Comment: The line numbers don't match in the error message and in the code you posted.  Are you sure you've saved the most recent changes to the file?

Comment: The code in traceback doesn't quite match the snippet you posted.  Could you edit one file, but execute/import another?

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake, it's my first post here, i tried to change stuff like paths and eliminate redundant parts in the snippets, I have updated them now with the integral copy-paste from my files. Sorry again!

Comment: Is the class definition necessary to reproduce the error? That is, what if you attempt to create an `np.array` at the very top of the imported module, under the imports? Does that still give the same error?

Comment: i tried inserting 'aa = np.array(2)' just under the imports in the module. If i execute the module.py i get no errors, if i import it the error is the same as before.

Comment: I'm mystified as to what's happening. But you can definitely pare down your [MRE] if that entire class definition is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: The fact that the line numbers in the error stay the same after adding the edit and the recently discovered fact that the code runs if i execute it in a py file instead of a ipynb file probably means the problem is not in the code itself but in what it's importing, may be an error with the interpreter? What checks should i perform for it?

Comment: Can you tell us how you are executing your code? E.g. `python main.py` Your file/folder structure might also be helpful.

Comment: Sure, the main file is a .ipynb i'm running cell by cell, the other two are .py files i'm running from terminal with 'python module.py'. All the files are in the same directory.

Comment: if you are running on a jupyter notebook then it could be that the imports are on a cell that you haven't run yet. That would explain that `np` is not defined

Comment: The imports are in the same cell the instruction that gave the error is run, the first one i pasted.